# Reofund command does not work in discord.py with no errors

Tags: python, file, discord, discord.py

I am building discord bot, and recently, I added system that can track your order so you can refound it if you don't want the item. I am getting no errors, but that can be a bug because I have this problem with my hosting provider for quite a long time.

Here is the code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def refound(ctx, order="None", *, reason="None"):
    if order in "None":
        await ctx.channel.send("Please enter valid order id")
    else:
        try:
            f = open(f"./all/orders/{order}.txt")
            content = f.read()
            f.close()
        except:
            await ctx.channel.send(f"We don't record any order with ID {order}")
            content = "error"
        if str(ctx.author.id) in content:
            if reason in "None":
                await ctx.channel.send("To save us time, please provde us a reason of your refound. Thank you.")
            else:
                try:
                    f = open(f"./all/refound/requests/{order}.txt", "r+")
                    f.close()
                    await ctx.channel.send("You refound is being procesed. Please be patient. We will be in touch as soon as possible.")
                except:
                    try:
                        f = open(f"./all/refound/completed/{order}.txt", "r+")
                        f.close()
                        await ctx.channel.send("Refound of this order was already processed!")
                    except:
                        f = open(f"./all/refounds/requests/{order}.txt", "w+")
                        f.write(f"Reason : {reason}")
                        f.close()
                        await ctx.channel.send("Refound requested. We will be in touch as soon as possible!")
                        
                        f = open(f"./all/orders/{order}.txt", "r+")
                        a = f.read()
                        f.close()
                        
                        a = a.replace("Successfull", "Requested refound")
                        
                        f = open(f"./all/orders/{order}.txt", "w+")
                        f.ssek(0)
                        f.write(a)
                        f.close()
        elif content in "error":
            pass
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send("You can only refound your own orders!")
```

Comment: Just from eyeballing, it's "refund", f.ssk(0) should be f.seek(0); you could just open the txt files once and I don't really understand your nested exception handling.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling too lol. Also, f.ssk should be f.seek, and I am just blind and don't see it till I am not looking for it. Thanks for help